# contar determinadas palabras en una tabla mysql

Tags: mysql

Hola me gustaría saber como se puede contabilizar determinadas palabras de una columna en una tabla de mysql por ejemplo en esta tabla:

```
+----+-----------+----------------------------------+------------------+
| id | queuename | agent                            | event            |
+----+-----------+----------------------------------+------------------+
|  1 | NONE      | NONE                             | QUEUESTART       |
|  2 | NONE      | NONE                             | QUEUESTART       |
|  3 | NONE      | NONE                             | QUEUESTART       |
|  4 | NONE      | NONE                             | QUEUESTART       |
|  5 | 000001999 | Local/POS01-100@000001_inbound_q | ADDMEMBER        |
|  6 | 000001999 | Local/POS02-101@000001_inbound_q | ADDMEMBER        |
|  7 | 000001999 | NONE                             | ENTERQUEUE       |
|  8 | 000001999 | NONE                             | ABANDON          |
|  9 | 000001999 | NONE                             | ENTERQUEUE       |
| 10 | 000001999 | NONE                             | ABANDON          |
| 11 | 000001999 | NONE                             | ENTERQUEUE       |
| 12 | 000001999 | NONE                             | ABANDON          |
| 13 | 000001999 | NONE                             | ENTERQUEUE       |
| 14 | 000001999 | NONE                             | ABANDON          |
| 15 | 000001999 | NONE                             | ENTERQUEUE       |
| 16 | 000001999 | NONE                             | ABANDON          |
| 17 | 000001999 | NONE                             | ENTERQUEUE       |
| 18 | 000001999 | <100> Recepcion                  | CONNECT          |
| 19 | 000001999 | <100> Recepcion                  | ATTENDEDTRANSFER |
| 20 | 000001999 | NONE                             | ENTERQUEUE       |
+----+-----------+----------------------------------+------------------+
```

De esa tabla me gustaria sacar el numero de veces que aparece queuestart y addmember...

por ejemplo si sale `queuestart` 5 veces pues que con un `select` o como sea me diga `queuestart 5`

Comment: Puedes emplear la función de agregación COUNT y la clausula GROUP BY https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select event, count(event) as total
from tabla
where event = 'QUEUESTART' or event = 'ADDMEMBER'
group by event;
```

En esta consulta se hace un filtro en la **claúsula** **where** donde solamente, se tendrán en cuenta los **event** cuyo valor sea **'QUEUESTART'** o **'ADDMEMBER'**, tal como indicas en tu planteamiento. Una vez que se hace ese filtro se hace una agrupación por el propio **campo** **event** y por último se proyectará en la consulta resultante el **campo** **event** y otra columna que tendrá la cantidad de veces que se repite ese valor del **campo** **event**, a esa columna se le da como alias **total**, y se usará la **función de agregación** **count** la cual cuenta todos los registros iguales de la agrupación realizada.

Si desea obtener el total de todos los valores de event pues quita la **claúsula where**, quedaría de esta forma:

```
select event, count(event) as total
from tabla
group by event;
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres que el resultado te salga si o si     `queuestart 5` puedes hacerlo con un CONCAT() para formatear la salida de la consulta. La consulta la haría de esta forma:

```
SELECT CONCAT("queuestart", " ", COUNT(*)) as nombre_que_quieras FROM nombre_tabla WHERE event="QUEUESTART";
```

Si hay 5 "QUEUESTART", esa consulta devolverá:

```
+--------------------+
| nombre_que_quieras |
+--------------------+
| queuestart 5       |
+--------------------+
```

Si quieres que cuente todas las palabras por separado, es decir, no sólo "QUEUESTART", la consulta sería:

```
SELECT CONCAT(event, " ", COUNT(*)) as nombre_que_quieras FROM nombre_tabla GROUP BY event;
```

Esa consulta devuelve:

```
+--------------------+
| nombre_que_quieras |
+--------------------+
| QUEUESTART 4       |
| ADDMEMBER 2        |
| ENTERQUEUE 7       |
| ABANDON 5          |
| CONNECT 1          |
| ATTENDTRANSFER 1   |
+--------------------+
```

(Creo que he contado bien cada palabra)

Si no quieres que aparezca lo de "nombre_que_quieras", añade "-N" al iniciar mysql. (Si inicias mysql con el comando `"mysql -u root -p"`, añádele `"mysql -N -u root -p"` aunque esto quitará la cabecera para todas tus consultas hasta que vuelvas a iniciar mysql sin el "-N"). Además, quítale la parte de `"as nombre_que_quieras"` aunque no pasaría nada si no lo quitas ya que no se verá de todas formas.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Un saludo.